# recyclerview rows IGNORE duplicates

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an app where i capture an image and save it with the name of the DATE to firebase real time database.

I retrieve the names of my images (DATES) from my MainActivity to a Recyclerview in a different activity.

When I call the camera in MainActivity it automatically uploads the file when captured. This is the code for uploading the image:

```
 private void uploadFile() {
    final String bothStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH mm ss").format(new Date());
    final String dateStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(new Date());
    final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH mm ss").format(new Date());

    if (mImageUri != null) {
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(bothStamp
                + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Upload upload = new Upload(
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(), dateStamp, timeStamp );

                        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
```

Then I have my UPLOAD class:

```
public class Upload {

private String mTime;
private String mName;
private String mImageUrl;


public Upload() {
    //empty constructor 
}

public Upload(String imageUrl, String name, String time) {

    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    mName = name;
    mTime = time;

}


public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}




public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
}
```

Then I have my ADAPTER for the recyclerview:

```
public class DateListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DateListAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;



public DateListAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {

    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}


@Override
public DateListAdapter.ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.date_list, parent, false);
    return new DateListAdapter.ImageViewHolder(v);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    String dateName = uploadCurrent.getName();

        holder.textViewName.setText(dateName);
    }



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewName;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name_date);

    }
}
}
```

Right now, when I capture multiple images in one day, this is my Output:

[This is what my code output is right now in the user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apFZt.png)

And this is what I would like to have in my OUTPUT:

[This is what I would like to show in my RECYCLERVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS9Jb.png)

So my purpose is that I would like to create a CLEAN and simple USER interface. I dont want multiple DATES to be shown, I want only ONE date and then when the user clicks the date it should display ALL images captured on THAT date.

---

***This is the EventListener in my Activity for the RecyclerView:***

```
mDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);

                mUploads.add(upload);
            }


            mAdapter = new DateListAdapter(CapturedImageDateListActivity.this, mUploads);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
```

Comment: what you actually want to do.?
create a node for each date and store data in that node.

Comment: im not clear with your question yet.! please elaborate more.?

Comment: I would like to create a CLEAN and simple USER interface. I dont want multiple DATES to be shown, I want only ONE date and then when the user clicks the date it should display ALL images captured on THAT date!

Comment: One option is check the day of the system and only create a new date if isn't the same as today. But this isn't optime maybe :)

Comment: ok thats cool.! create a node for each each day(Date)  then store data in it.!

Comment: Are you talking about nodes in firebase ? What do you mean with node?

Comment: node is sort of table  where you can  store your data.! its basically
 no sql so we cant say it table.! its child of about database in which we store data.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data is being override while storing it because of same date.
All You have to do is store data according to current date.!
and now you can easily get data according to different dates.!

and do have a look at mine [Firebase Helper Class](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork/FireBaseHelper.java)

```
   final String dateStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(new Date());

ImageModel imageValue=new ImageModel(datestamp,imageUrl);

mdatabaseReference.child("imageGalleryNode").child(dateStamp).child(getRandomId()).setValue(imageValue)
```

and if you want to maintain each user data then .

```
mdatabaseReference.child("imageGalleryNode").child(dateStamp).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(getRandomId()).setValue(imageValue)



public String getRandomId() {

        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return id;
    }
```

and get data using firebase Event listener.!

```
ArrayList<String> dateNodeKeyList=new Arraylist<>();

 databaseReference = FireBaseHelper.getDataBaseRefrence();
        databaseReference.child("imageGalleryNode");



  databaseReference .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

if(dateNodeKeyList.size>0){ //to avoid data duplication on data change.
dateNodeKeyList.clear();
}

                  ArrayList<ImagesModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            // key for node .!
             String key = childSnapshot.getKey();
             dateNodeKeyList.add(key);

           // ImagesModel object =  
              childSnapshot.getValue(ImagesModel.class);

            arrayList.add(object);

        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {



                }
            });
```

and your `json` will be like this.!

```
{

  "26-02-2018": {
    "13d49659-8ab1-48b7-808b-987f43de9fbc": {
      "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2": {
        "imageName": "13d49659-8ab1-48b7-808b-987f43de9fbc",
        "imageUrl": 0,
        "imageid": "fa7d6135-64ba-4bbe-8b9e-078bc6171463",
        "userId": "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2"
      }
    },
    "51c51cec-ac6d-4766-823e-df9e27cfc169": {
      "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2": {
        "imageName": "51c51cec-ac6d-4766-823e-df9e27cfc169",
        "imageUrl": 0,
        "imageid": "f16185f4-05b6-4d77-8019-c09563e044ce",
        "userId": "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2"
      }
    }
  },
  "27-02-2018": {
    "13d49659-8ab1-48b7-808b-987f43de9fbc": {
      "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2": {
        "imageName": "13d49659-8ab1-48b7-808b-987f43de9fbc",
        "imageUrl": 0,
        "imageid": "fa7d6135-64ba-4bbe-8b9e-078bc6171463",
        "userId": "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2"
      }
    },
    "51c51cec-ac6d-4766-823e-df9e27cfc169": {
      "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2": {
        "imageName": "51c51cec-ac6d-4766-823e-df9e27cfc169",
        "imageUrl": 0,
        "imageid": "f16185f4-05b6-4d77-8019-c09563e044ce",
        "userId": "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2"
      }
    }
  },
  "28-02-2018": {
    "13d49659-8ab1-48b7-808b-987f43de9fbc": {
      "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2": {
        "imageName": "13d49659-8ab1-48b7-808b-987f43de9fbc",
        "imageUrl": 0,
        "imageid": "fa7d6135-64ba-4bbe-8b9e-078bc6171463",
        "userId": "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2"
      }
    },
    "51c51cec-ac6d-4766-823e-df9e27cfc169": {
      "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2": {
        "imageName": "51c51cec-ac6d-4766-823e-df9e27cfc169",
        "imageUrl": 0,
        "imageid": "f16185f4-05b6-4d77-8019-c09563e044ce",
        "userId": "DHFNJoa2hPdtM1sapeIFPQpDH7c2"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Now I have changed my code so I get similar output in Json as you.
So now I need to fetch the name of the "node" which is the date that the input was made in database (dateStamp) And display it in the RECYCLERVIEW

Comment: I have updated the post with my eventListener for Recyclerview. And by the way this is what my json looks like now : https://gyazo.com/10feaefbd59b544cf058e3e65c88444f

Comment: I dont want to display information from the child of 20180228.
I want to display the date 20180228.

Comment: ok then simply query on their parent node key .updated answer have a look @firozaqiwu